# Imagemagick desaturate black/white?

Tags: php, imagemagick

Would like to turn this into black and white.. can't figure out what to use from imagick..

```
$handle_data = file_get_contents('http://www.bungie.net/Stats/Reach/Nightmap.ashx');
//http://www.bungie.net/Stats/Halo3/Nightmap.ashx
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($handle_data);
$img->writeImage('nightmap/'.$time.'.gif');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Imagick::modulateImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-modulateimage.php) could be a quick&dirty solution. Dirty because color theory is a rather complex field, and there can be done more to create grayscale images than just desaturating the image (like applying different weights to the single color channels).

```
bool Imagick::modulateImage (float $brightness , float $saturation , float $hue)
```

Given an image, keep `brightness` and `hue` at 100%, while setting `saturation` to 0%. There is an example at the bottom of the documentation page that does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a much better (and just as simple) solution: `$im = $im->fxImage('intensity');`

That applies a function to the image, where intensity is equal to `0.299*red+0.587*green+0.114*blue`.

That formula is based on how our eyes are more sensitive to different colours, and as such the difference between that and a "flat" grayscale image really is night and day.

More details here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.fximage.php
- http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php