# imagick | Gradient map

Tags: php, image, filter, imagick

I'm trying to get this effect on images using imagick. In photoshop it's called a gradient-map, but I can't find anything similar to this in imagick.

I think I need to make it black-and-white first, but I don't get how to add the colors after doing so.

Hope you can help! Thanks

**--- EDIT: ---**

- I'm using **Imagick**, not imagemagick.
- Notice there are two colors in the image, it's not just colorized. Dark blue for the darker colors, and light green/aqua for the lighter ones.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**PHP Imagick Version**

Now I have understood your needs, I have done an Imagick PHP version:

```
<?php
   // Load input image
   $image = new Imagick('landscape.jpg');

   // Desaturate image
   $image->modulateImage(100,0,100);

   // Make duotone CLUT
   $clut = new Imagick();
   $clut->newPseudoImage(255,1,"gradient:darkblue-aqua");

   // Apply duotone CLUT to image
   $image->clutImage($clut);

   // Output result
   $image->writeImage('result.jpg');
?>
```

[image]

**Updated Answer**

Oh, I think you want a *"duotone"* rather than a *"tint"*. Basically, you need to desaturate your image to mono, make a duotone CLUT (Colour Lookup Table) and apply that.

Here is how to make a CLUT:

```
convert -size 1x256! gradient:navy-orange duotone-clut.png
```

[image]

This one will obviously make your dark tones navy and your highlights orange, but you can play around with the colours as you wish. You can also specify any shades of RGB (or HSL) as you wish with syntax like:

```
convert -size 1x256! gradient:"rgb(255,255,0)-rgb(23,45,100)" ...
```

Here is how to desaturate your image to grey and then apply the CLUT:

```
convert landscape.jpg -modulate 100,0 \
  -size 256x1! gradient:navy-orange -clut result.jpg
```

The `-modulate` takes 3 parameters - Hue, Saturation and Lightness. By specifying `100,0` I have left the Hue at 100% of whatever it was and reduced the Saturation to zero and left the Lightness unchanged.

[image]

By the way, if you want a *"tritone"* with a 3 colours, one for shadow, one for midtones and one for highlights, you can make one like this:

```
convert -size 1x1! xc:yellow xc:magenta xc:cyan +append -resize 256x1! -scale x20 clut.png
```

[image]

Which gives this:

[image]

You can also move the crossover points around in the CLUT, either using a contrast-stretch or by having a bigger proportion of your CLUT populated by the same colours. Here I make the shadow colour *"longer"* by having 2 yellow blocks.

```
convert -size 1x1! xc:yellow xc:yellow xc:magenta xc:cyan +append -resize 256x1!  clut.png
```

[image]

That gives *"longer"* shadows:

[image]

Obviously you can make a quadtone (quad-tone) too.

**Original Answer**

There are a number of ways of achieving the effect. So, starting with this image:

[image]

You could use `tint` like this, which corresponds to `tintImage()` in PHP, described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.tintimage.php):

```
convert landscape.jpg -colorspace gray -fill "rgb(10,100,130)" -tint 100 result.png
```

[image]

Or you could clone your initial image and fill the clone with your tint colour and then composite that over the top of your image. You would use `colorizeImage()` in PHP, described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.colorizeimage.php):

```
convert landscape.jpg -colorspace gray                  \
   \( +clone -fill "rgb(10,100,130)" -colorize 100% \)  \
   -compose overlay -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I didn't check StackOverflow for a while. Thanks for your answer, but it's not the same effect i'm affraid, and I'm using Imagick, not imagemagick like in your example. Notice that there are two colors in my example, dark blue and aqua-green-ish. The dark colors are converted to blue, while the lighter colors are converted to aqua.

Comment: @Ronald Ok, I think I have got the idea now. Please have another look. We can work on a PHP conversion later if it looks like it will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, it is indeed exactly the effect i'm looking for! But i'm affraid it's still in imagemagick, in stead of imagick, which is a different language. :)

Comment: Ok, I'll convert it later for you now we know what we're aiming for. It's easier to protype things at the commandline with ImageMagick for me.

Comment: alright! i'm a first-time user for both of them, so i'm very glad you're helping me! thanks again :)

Comment: I wish there were more ImageMagick walkthroughs like this to explain reproducing an effect, super helpful to understand what those flags are doing. I ended up with `convert source.jpg -colorspace gray -level +10% +level-colors "#44607f","#c1d6d8" treated.jpg` to achieve a similar effect (blathered about it at http://blog.clixel.com/post/118816247013/duotone-images-with-imagemagick-in-wordpress), but this approach feels more adaptable.

Comment: Check out [pslayers](https://github.com/darrynten/pslayers) - I mentioned it in an answer below (shameless self plug etc etc)

Comment: it might be worth noting that using the black & white conversion could be better achieved with a function like `$image->fxImage('intensity');` rather than `$image->modulateImage(100,0,100);` due to colour perception.

See [SO Imagick Desaturate Black\White](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34072207/1577447) and [ImageMagick's FX Image documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php).

Answer (score 0):

There's a library for PHP Imagick called [pslayers](https://github.com/darrynten/pslayers) and it allows you to do the exact kind of image layering and compositing that you are describing.

It even allows you to create interfaces to command line scrips for interacting with the command line version directly.