# PHP : Convert dynamic uploaded image to specific color(dynamic color)

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

I have a simple `HTML` form where the user can upload their image and I need to convert this uploaded image into a specific color with the help of `PHP`

For example, user upload some image I need to convert the entire image into a specific color (this color is dynamic)

Is there any `PHPGD` library that can help me to achieve this?

**EDIT**

For example, user is uploading this kind of Image,

[image]

then I need to convert into below type of Image,

[image]

Comment: Install and use the [Imagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) library. It is wondrous for doing... a lot. Including this.

Comment: Thanks, do you know any example maybe? never worked with Imagick, any example can be much helpful

Comment: Kindly provide sample input image and expected result. Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36825769/2836621

Comment: there is no specific or sample Image, as a user can upload any valid image and I need to convert any Image to my color, so you can consider any Image.

Comment: It's not very clear at all. I send you a picture of the Queen and you change it to blue and send me back a solid blue image the same size as the original?

Comment: ok, let me update some sample to make it more clear :)

Comment: Please see my edit @MarkSetchell

Comment: Ok, so how do we know which colours to make red? I mean, in your example we need to make blue into red, yellow into red and red into red but somehow we magically know not to make white into red? What about creamy white - must that stay creamy white or go red? What about black? I'm not being argumentative, I just want to understand the criteria so I, or someone else, can help you.

Comment: ok in my case I need to Ignore white color, rest of the color I need to convert, as of now I don't have a specific color list to ignore expect white(#FFF)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm still unsure exactly what you are trying to do, but think one of the following may be close. Maybe you can try them in the Terminal until we can finally work out the correct operations then we can hopefully translate them into PHP. This is **ImageMagick** v7 syntax:

```
magick image.png -channel RGB -colorspace gray +level-colors red,  result.png
```

[image]

Or this:

```
magick image.png -fill red +opaque white result2.png
```

[image]

You can specify the colour in hex like this for magenta:

```
magick image.png -channel RGB -colorspace gray -auto-level +level-colors '#ff00ff',  result.png
```

If using v6 **ImageMagick**, replace `magick` with `convert`.

---

My PHP is pretty rusty, but something like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -f
<?php

// Emulating something akin to this ImageMagick command:
// magick image.png -fill red +opaque white result.png
// Open input image and get dimensions
$im = new \Imagick('image.png');

// Temporarily deactivate alpha channel
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_DEACTIVATE);

// Apply colour to non-white areas
$im->opaquePaintImage('white','red', 0, true);

// Reactivate alpha channel
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_ACTIVATE);

// Save
$im->writeImage('result.png');
?>
```

Comment: Awesome Mark!!!!!!! with the command line it works really cool, this is exactly what I was looking for, with the code pool do you have Idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: I cobbled together some PHP, please have another look.

Comment: with the code, it also applied color to white color as well,

Comment: It works fine on my machine on the sample image you provided. Are you maybe using a different image?

Comment: Yes, I used different image (I used 15 different image with the command it works really good) . did you check with some different image?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. First you implied it does not work because it applies colour to white, then in your last comment you say it works with 15 different images really well. If it doesn't work, please click `edit` under your original question and add in the image that doesn't work and also the exact code you used and the result you got. Thank you.

Comment: ok, so what I am saying I checked 15 different images(including question image) when you provided the command and it works really well but with the PHP code it works only with the question image, not for all images, apologies for misunderstanding, any idea?

Comment: Not really without seeing the images that don't work.

Comment: Try changing the zero after `'red'` to 15000... your whites may not be perfectly white which is what I was asking earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216886/discussion-between-keyur-shah-and-mark-setchell).

Comment: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcThbFhvvFUbfig3ICA1Snif_NZfP95I9MTWhw&usqp=CAU please check this sample Image

Comment: The new image works fine. I use PHP 7.4.7 with Imagick 3.4.4 and ImageMagick 7.0.10.

Comment: Need to check, I have ImageMagick 7.0.10 and PHP 7.2.30 in my case it is not working :(

Comment: If you run `magick -version` in Terminal, is your ImageMagick Q8 or Q16. If Q8, try replacing the zero after `'red'` in my code with 64.

Comment: I have Q16, here is the output, `Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-22 Q16 x86_64 2020-06-27 https://imagemagick.org
`

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to produce something similar. Please test the following code if that satisfies your requirement.

```
 <?PHP
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 /*
  @desc replaces target color of an image with the provided fill color

 */
 function color_replace($img,$target,$fill,$fuzz){

          $img->opaquePaintImage($target, $fill, $fuzz, false, Imagick::CHANNEL_DEFAULT);
          return $img;
 }

$img = new Imagick('source.png');
$img->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_DEACTIVATE);
$fuzz = 0.44 * $img->getQuantumRange()['quantumRangeLong'];
$img=color_replace($img,'rgba(50,173,186,255)','red',$fuzz); // replace paste like color with red
$img=color_replace($img,'rgb(230,218,30)','#9c1f24',$fuzz); // replace golden like color with dark red

$img->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_ACTIVATE);

$img->setImageFormat ("jpeg");
file_put_contents ("test_1.jpg", $img);

?>
```

Produced output with my program:

[image]

With this program, you will be able to change each individual color by calling the `color_replace` method every time you want to change color. The following image is an example of that.

[image]

Comment: How can I know #9c1f24 color is I need to replace? as this image is not static, it is dynamic and the user can upload any type of Image,

Comment: How about taking the user input. For example, with a color picker, we can easily take their input. But problem could be with wrong input. I will think more to give you an idea. Probably, eye dropper behavior of photo editor could automatically pick all the colors from the photo and ask user for the replacement color. But I will think more. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need some library like [`Imagick`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php). To replace some color, you need [`clutImage`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.clutimage.php)

```php
$image = new Imagick('test.jpg');
$clut = new Imagick();
$clut->newImage(1, 1, new ImagickPixel('rgb(255, 0, 0)'));
$image->clutImage($clut);
$image->writeImage('test_out.jpg');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, For example, I uploaded the picture with multiple colors, then how can I do this? here I can see you passed only 1 color

Comment: @KeyurShah So loop your color replacements

Comment: how can I find my all Image color?

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution for you here, again of course with Imagick:

```
$im = new Imagick('path/to/start-image')
$im->transformimagecolorspace(Imagick::IMGTYPE_GRAYSCALE);
$im->writeImage('path/to/gray.jpg'));
$im->clear();

$im = new Imagick('path/to/gray.jpg'));
$im->blackThresholdImage( "#cdcdcd" );
$im->writeImage('path/to/black-white.jpg'));
$im->clear();

$im = new Imagick('path/to/black-white.jpg'));
$im->colorizeImage('rgba(209, 15, 16, 1)', 1, true);
$im->writeImage('path/to/red.jpg'));
$im->clear();
```

Then just delete the intermediate files gray.jpg and black-white.jpg and you will achieve the result you are looking for as here:

[image: Transformed to red]